# Datagridview - Datatable-Serialize

Tags: c#

C# - Tengo una lista de datos en mi Datagridview, lo que busco es que, cuando le de clic en el boton guardar. todos lo datos del Datagridview se almacenen en un datatable para luego ser serializado y esto se envié a la capa de negocio y posteriormente a la capas de datos para ser gestionado mediante un procedimiento almacenado. Espero su apoyo.

```
    private void btnXml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();

         // Agregamos columnas a la tabla de datos

         foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dvgClientes.Columns)

         {

             dt.Columns.Add(col.DataPropertyName, col.ValueType);

         }

         //agregamos nuevas filas

         foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dvgClientes.Rows)

         {

             DataRow row1 = dt.NewRow();

             for (int i = 0; i < dvgClientes.ColumnCount; i++)

                 //si el valor existe, agregue ese valor, de lo contrario agregue Nulo para ese campo

                 row1[i] = (row.Cells[i].Value == null ? DBNull.Value : row.Cells[i].Value);

             dt.Rows.Add(row1);

         }

         //Agregamos el datatable los datos

         ds.Tables.Add(dt);


    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y dónde tienes exactamente el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser una mejor manera de hacerlo, pero de lo contrario sería bastante trivial simplemente recorrer el DGV y crear el DataTable manualmente.

Algo como esto podría funcionar:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
{
   dt.Columns.Add(col.Name);    
}

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
    DataRow dRow = dt.NewRow();
    foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
}
```